# ScrollView não rola a tela em modo Landscape

Tags: android-studio, rolamento

Olá,

O ScrollView não rola a tela em modo Landscape. Em modo Portrait funciona normalmente.

Já fiz o xml com e sem o android:scrollbars="vertical".

---

segue o código xml:

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:background="@color/branco"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tblMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:stretchColumns="2">...
```

Existem mais elementos, mas o código acima já deve dar para se ter uma ideia da configuração:

A imagem do programa está abaixo:

[image: Tela]

Não dá pra ver na captura da imagem, mas estou tentando rolar a imagem com o mouse no emulador. A barra de rolagem não aparece e a tela não rola para baixo. Coloquei o mesmo texto de cima e até pus uma cor diferente para diferenciar um texto do outro e poder ver que o texto está cortado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido,

Em algum momento, eu, sem querer, cliquei em **Create Landscape Variation**.

Por isso o landscape não estava conseguindo "*se encontrar*" com os pixels de tela do emulador e assumia que a tela não tinha sido virada.

Fui na pasta do app, pelo Windows Explorer, e deletei todas as pastas que continham as "Activity" relacionadas ao Landscape criado e deixei apenas a "Activity" principal.

Agora está normal.